# ModuleNotFoundError in PyCharm

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I have a custom Python library in `D:\projects\data_downloader`. I added this path to `Interpreter Paths` in PyCharm. As I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), the added corresponding path is `/mnt/d/projects/data_downloader`.

When I try to use import statement (i.e. `import data_downloader` or `from data_downloader import image_downloader`) I get ***Unresolved reference 'data_downloader'*** highlight in PyCharm.

When I open my Python console (directly from PyCharm or automatically when I want to run some code that is using this import) I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sondracek/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-78bb803718fb>", line 1, in <module>
    from data_downloader import image_downloader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_downloader'
```

When I check `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` the added path to my library is really missing, so it is obvious why I receive `ModuleNotFoundError`. When I manually add this path (`/mnt/d/projects/data_downloader`) to `PATH` manually after opening Python console I can use (import) `data_downloader` lib without any issue.

Any idea on what is happening and why adding library path directly in PyCharm doesn't work? (It seems like an issue with WSL?) See my question asked [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006931680-PyCharm-interpreter-paths-for-WSL-interpreter).